# Apache Camel : Azure Blob to Azure Blob Route, File Transfer Feasibility

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

We got a use case to retrieve some files from Azure Blob Storage #1 and upload it to another Azure Blob Storage #2. Is it a feasible way in which it can be implemented via Apache Camel.

I have tried with a sample route included below, however its not working in the expected format, ended up in below exception.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream mark expired.
> at com.azure.storage.common.StorageInputStream.reset(StorageInputStream.java:366) ~[azure-storage-common-12.11.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.camel.component.azure.storage.blob.BlobUtils.getInputStreamLength(BlobUtils.java:38) ~[camel-azure-storage-blob-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
> at org.apache.camel.component.azure.storage.blob.BlobStreamAndLength.createBlobStreamAndLengthFromExchangeBody(BlobStreamAndLength.java:50) ~[camel-azure-storage-blob-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
> at org.apache.camel.component.azure.storage.blob.operations.BlobOperations.uploadBlockBlob(BlobOperations.java:182) ~[camel-azure-storage-blob-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]
> at org.apache.camel.component.azure.storage.blob.BlobProducer.process(BlobProducer.java:89) ~[camel-azure-storage-blob-3.12.0.jar:3.12.0]

```
from("azure-storage-blob://storage_name/container?accessKey=xxx&blobName=int_1111.csv")
.to("azure-storage-blob://storage_name/container?accessKey=xxx&blobName=Outbound_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.csv&operation=uploadBlockBlob");
```

UPDATE : When I convert the body to byte[], I was able to upload the file content to Azure blob, however this might impact the memory when dealing with large files.

```
from("azure-storage-blob://storage_name/container?accessKey=xxx&blobName=int_1111.csv")
.convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
.to("azure-storage-blob://storage_name/container?accessKey=xxx&blobName=Outbound_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.csv&operation=uploadBlockBlob");
```

Any suggestion or feedback to handle the file upload in a better way.

Comment: I am getting error with similar scenario.   c.a.storage.common.StorageInputStream    : Stream is already closed.

Comment: Have you tried the .convertBodyTo() method to see if it resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've raised a ticket with Camel framework team to incorporate the Azure Copy Blob operation in starter pack - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17161.

They have added the feature and its available from 3.14.0 version of azure blob starter pack, if anyone is interested in exploring the functionality, please feel free to check the documentation page for examples.

```
from("azure-storage-blob://storage_account_name/container_1?accessKey=xxxxxx&blobName=int_1111.csv")
.process(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(BlobConstants.BLOB_NAME, "int_1111.csv");
        exchange.getMessage().setHeader(BlobConstants.SOURCE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME, "container_1");
        exchange.getMessage().setHeader(BlobConstants.SOURCE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME, "storage_account_name");
      })
.to("azure-storage-blob://storage_account_name/container_2?accessKey=xxxxxx&operation=copyBlob&sourceBlobAccessKey=xxxxxx");
```

Copy Blob API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob

Maven Repo link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-azure-storage-blob-starter/3.14.0

Examples (refer copy blob section):
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/azure-storage-blob-component.html

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Download  `blockBlob` located on the `container1` in the `Account1` storage account

```
from("azure-storage-blob:/Account1/container1?blobName=blobname&accessKey=yourAccessKey").
to("file://blobdirectory");
```

For more details refer this [document](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/components/camel-azure/src/main/docs/azure-blob-component.adoc)

**2)**  Upload the downloaded blob to  another `container2` in the `account2` storage account

**Example:**

```
from("file://blobdirectory ").to("azure-blob://storage2 /container2/BLOB1?credentials=#credentials&operation=updateBlockBlob")
```

For more details refer this [document](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/azure-storage-blob-component.html)

Comment: Do we really require a file route while transferring file from one Azure blob to another Azure blob ? I would like to get some information based on your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more what you looking for?

Comment: In your solution, a file component / app directory being used to transfer file from one blob to another isn't it? Is it a recommended way when we transfer file from one cloud location to another location? I would like to understand more on this approach you suggested as currently I used a direct component in between the download and upload operation to Azure blob.